# Как задать строковый массив?

Tags: winapi, c++

Подскажите, как в Win32 сделать массив, который будет хранить строки?

**Дополнено.**

Мне нужно не сразу выводить строку, а после того как введу n-ое количество строк и вывести те, которые подходят под условие, поэтому мне надо их где-то хранить!

Вот код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    LPTSTR mas[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        gets(mas[i]);
        printf("%s", mas[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пишет всё необьявленный идентификатор.

Comment: У меня идёт поток символов, мне нужно вывести на экран те строки, которые больше 80 символов. Вот для того чтоб их хранить где-то мне нужен массив строк.

Comment: Убирал, на 2 необьявленных идентификатора меньше..

Comment: А если подумать? Попробуйте еще <tchar.h> подцепить. Может придется еще какие-нить макросы определить. Вроде UNICODE. А еще неплохо приводить сообщения об ошибках полностью. Да и, честно говоря, мне неясно чем vector<string> не понравился.

Comment: Я пишу в Visual C++ 2010 и в нём нет операторов таких как cout cin и т.д. поэтому я незнаю как задать вектор в нём(( то что вы предложили может и есть решение проблемы, но как будет выглядеть код, не имею представления..

Comment: Посмотрите справку по VC++. Чтоб использовать cout и cin нужно написать `std::cout` и `std::cin` соответственно. Изучите что такое namespaces.

Comment: Спасибо, будем учить.. З.Ы. читаю книжку Б. Керниган, Д. Ритчи Язык программирования Си.

Comment: Книжка хорошая, но не про C++.

Answer (score 3):

"Спасибо, будем учить.. З.Ы. читаю книжку Б. Керниган, Д. Ритчи Язык программирования Си."

Книжка очень хорошая. Будем говорить о Си (без плюсов).

На мой взгляд, Ваша проблема в том, что в Си **нет встроенного типа "строка"**. Есть встроенный тип **символ (char)**. Символы могут агрегироваться в **массивы** и таким образом располагаться в смежных (последовательных) байтах памяти. Объявляем так:

```
char string[1000];  // это массив из 1000 байт (символов)
```

Строкой в Си называют такой массив, а точнее **его начальные байты, завершающиеся нулем (двоичным)**. Когда мы пишем строковую константу, например

```
сhar *s = "строковая константа";  // это тоже называется строкой
```

компилятор выделяет память под эти символы (создает массив достаточного размера) и **заносит его адрес** в переменную s (ее тип - **указатель на символ(ы)**).

В Вашем случае массив строк на самом деле должен быть **массивом указателей на символы**.

```
char *array[1000];  // здесь будем хранить адреса прочитанных строк (до 1000)
char buffer[1000];  // а сюда будем считывать очередную строку
int  n = 0;         // счетчик прочитанных строк
while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) { // почему так, почитайте man-pages
    array[n++] = strdup(buffer);  // копируем прочитанную строку в динамическую память
                                  // и запоминаем адрес копии
}
// по концу стандартного ввода попали сюда
int  i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (strlen(array[i]) > 80)
        fputs (array[i],stdout);  // опять читаем man puts и fputs
```

Переполнение array[] и слишком длинные строки отследите сами.

При желании array можно сделать динамическим, объявив его char **array и самостоятельно разместив его в памяти, увеличивая по мере необходимости. Для этого почитайте о realloc().

Comment: Ответ хороший. Чисто по C.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, завтра буду пробывать.

Answer (score 2):

Чистым С++ (с STL) - `std::vector<std::string> mas;`

WinAPI - `LPTSTR mas[];` // массив указателей на строки

MFC - `CStringArray mas;`

Comment: Надо какую-то библиотеку подключать? Бо он мне выдал кучу ошибок..

Comment: Да.
Для первого 

    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

Для второго

    #include <winnt.h> // только под Windows

Для третьего
    
    #include <afxcoll.h> // а также зависимости из MFC и Windows PSDK

Comment: Пасиб огромное, есть ICQ? если появятся ещё вопросы у новичка?)

Comment: При подключении #include <winnt.h> библиотеки выдало 173 ошибки))

Comment: попробуйте `#include <windows.h>`. По идее все равно эти заголовочные файлы должны каскадно подключаться.

Comment: уже 7 ошибок, но всёравно мимо(

Comment: А что есть символьная строка в Вашем случае? И символьный массив? В простейшем -- массив символов, т.е. элементы имеют тип `char`

Comment: Соглашусь с @alexlz в том ключе, что можно массив строк затолкать в char [], только вот удобным это решение не назовешь, т.к будет сложно искать конкретную строку. Далее - осень интересно посмотреть какие именно семь ошибок при компиляции получились?